# Can ANTLR generate a parser class that is final?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlrworks

I'm using ANTLR 3.1 and ANTLRWorks to generate a parser class in Java. The parser performs better if I mark the generated class with the Java final keyword. The problem is: I am adding this keyword manually after each time I re-generated the code from the ANTLR grammar. Is there anyway, in the grammar, of telling ANTLR to add the final keyword to the generated parser class definition?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Java are you using? The more recent ones should detect leaf classes automatically, as should any since 1.3 in -server mode.

Comment: I'm using 1.6 in -server mode. Even so, omitting the final keyword does seem to add ~30% to the timings.

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357695/how-do-you-specify-the-access-specifier-on-an-antlr-v3-generated-parser-or-lexer) (oops- my bad), it looks like it's not possible to do it yet. :(